# Anomaly detection problem

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Мне нужно создать нейронную сеть которая найдет в данных аномалии. Есть станок с 40 параметрами за каждый час на протяжении 3 лет. Известно, что в этих данных есть 13 поломок. Информация по 10 из них есть: дата поломки, причина, продолжительность устранения,дата устранения. 
Я делаю так:

1. Создаю train dataframe куда включаю 10 аномалий и все наблюдения где для любого параметра нет аномалий (аномалией параметра называю его значение, которые выходят за 2 - 3 сигмы)
2. Обучаю нейронку
3. Показываю нейронке оставшиеся данные. Она должна выявить аномалии.

У меня есть 10, известных мне поломок. Среди них есть 2 поломки которые произошли в один день, но имели разные продолжительности.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы эти две поломки считались в train как две разные? Ну, чтобы не обучать нейронку каждый раз сначала на 1ой поломке, потом на второй и т.д. а чтобы сразу на всех 10.

Comment: можете выложить ваш датасет на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имели ввиду под последовательным обучением. Ведь для того, что бы сеть обучить, ей надо скормить всю обучающую выборку. В вашем случае все примеры с поломками (10 примеров)и все примеры без поломок.

Что до вопроса про две поломки в один день - я бы попробовал бы вообще убрать дату из данных. Тогда данные точно не будут восприниматься как одна поломка.

Куда серьезнее у вас проблема связанная с тем, что выборка ваша очень несбалансированная. И вот тут надо сильно думать, что с этим делать.